# Orbiting camera around center of screen

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to setup my camera to orbit around the center of the screen, rather than just rotating the camera itself, and without having a target game object.

I'm able to orbit around a game object very easily using:

```
float rotationAmount = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * RotateAmount;
transform.RotateAround(target, Vector3.up, rotationAmount);
```

However I want to have a similar orbit mechanic without a target. For an example, see the [Planet Coaster camera controls](https://youtu.be/zZntCyeXhac?t=30s).

I have tried using `ScreenToWorldPoint` to try and get the middle of the screen but that seems to still just rotate the camera:

```
camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2, camera.nearClipPlane));
```

One thing that did work is using `Vector3.zero` as a target. However, if I translate the camera this vector still points to `(0,0,0)` and so the camera moves in a strange way.

Is there any way to orbit around the center of the screen without a target?

Comment: You could place a cube as a child for your camera and rotate around it with the first method you described. You can also make the cube invisible by disabling its renderer.

Comment: @Hristo I thought about having an invisible object to rotate around, but the question remains of how to position it. If I make it a child of the camera I would need to offset it's position to essentially be on the ground ahead of the camera. But that may as well be the point I rotate around anyway.

Comment: yeah otherwise you could offset it a few meters in front of the camera and have that as the default pivot point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put camera inside a GameObject (let's call it CameraHolder), offset the camera back a bit (just make sure CameraHolder is on the camera's forward positive axis). Now use your controls to control the CameraHolder instead of the camera:

1. If you want to move the camera around, move the CameraHolder's position instead. Because the camera is a child of CameraHolder, it will keep its localPosition and move along. The trick though, is to move using camera.transform's vectors:

   - To move forward: `CameraHolder.position += camera.transform.forward`
   - To move right: `CameraHolder.position += camera.transform.right`

This way you always move relative to the camera's view.

Furthermore, if you want an RTS control just like Planet Coaster (slide along a plane - in this case, the ground), you will need to limit `CameraHolder.transform.position.y` to the ground. You can either set `y` to a fixed value after each movement or just remove the `y` part from `camera.transform.forward/right`.

2. If you want to rotate the camera around, simply change CameraHolder's rotation, the camera will rotate along. For this case, you will need to limit max-min angle (most likely between 0 and -90 degree)

Comment: I don't see how this is different to just moving the camera itself. I already have translation control directly on the camera. I'd still have the same problem of positioning the cameraholder to orbit correctly.

Comment: Translation control is the same in both cases, but CameraHolder serve as a pivot for the camera to rotate around. In other words, CameraHolder's position is where the camera is looking at. So when you want to rotate, instead of using RotateAround, just change `CameraHolder.transform.rotation` directly with `Quaternion.Eulers` or whichever way you prefer. This method also allow you to limit camera view angle, which your original method doesn't support.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer because, while I used a slightly different movement and rotation script, you're answer put me onto using a parent GameObject (actually 2, one to translate and rotate and one to pivot). For future readers, this is very similar to the FreeLookCam script in the Unity standard assets.

Comment: Any chance to provide a code snippet for this? I am sure a lot of people would be happy to see a working version of a script for this.